# Keyboard shortcut for flagging in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a keyboard shortcut in outlook 2007 to flag an email instead of having to mouse click the little flag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Edit:**  You can also just press <kbd>Insert</kbd> if you just want to mark it with the default flag.  Additionally, pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> on an already flagged item marks it as completed.

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey could do it!

Use the `Click` function.

What you want to do is install AHK, then use the bundled Window Spy to find out the position of the button. Then you'd use something like this:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class [whatever outlook's class is, the window spy will reveal this]
[your hotkey here]::Click, X of flag, Y of flag
#IfWinActive
```

edit: djhowell says you can use Control+Shift+G, then return. In this case your hotkey would be:

```
[hotkey]::Send !+G{Return}
```

Keep it simple!