# Outlook 2013 - Keyboard shortcut for filtering email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

One of the things I do frequently in Outlook is to [flag messages for which I have action items](https://superuser.com/questions/63143), then go back later and use the Filter Email feature on the Home tab to show only those messages I have previously flagged:

[image: Screenshot of Filter Email operation]

I would like to do this using a keyboard shortcut, but I haven't been able to find one. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this, or a way to create a custom one?

Comment: I guess another way to ask this is, is there a way to define a custom search, since this action just inserts "followupflag:follup flag" into the search box?

Comment: @Dave, that ticket is about flagging emails in the first place. What I'm looking for is getting to a filtered view of previously-flagged emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and you'll see the hidden shortcuts. As you press the shortcut key (character) it's possible other shortcuts are exposed.

For your request, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> then <kbd>H</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd> and then <kbd>F</kbd>

You can then create a mapped key easily enough in AutoHotKey. This is assigned to ALT+F

```
!F::
Send {Alt}
Send {H}
Send {L}
Send {F}
```

Comment: Do you know a way to trigger the filter like using the sorting feature in the conversation list? see my answer with screenshot below

Answer (score 0):

This is amazing!

Another a maybe a faster way to accomplish the same would be to do the following:

;filter for unread emails in folder
!U::
Send {F3}
SendInput isread:no
Return

;filter for flagged emails in folder
!F::
Send {F3}
SendInput followupflag:followup flag
Return